# さて vs. そして: When should you use one or the other?

Tags: word-choice, words, conjunctions

The title pretty well summarizes the question.  さて vs. そして: When should you use one or the other?  How are they different?  To me, they come across as being used very similarly, at least when at the beginning of a sentence, but even then, there are probably different little nuances.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

さて is a "decorative" word and is used like "Now,.." or "So, ..". It doesn't really matter even if you omit it.

> **さて**、始めましょうか。: **So**, let's get started.

そして is a coordinating conjunction and can be translated into "Then," or "After that".

> 空が暗くなって、**そして** 雨がふりだした。: The sky got dark, **then** it started raining.

Also, it could simply mean "and". For example,

> 私は新聞と傘、**そして** チョコレートを買った。: I got newspaper, an umbrella, **and** a chocolate.